# Bloc listener not triggering navigation in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Can anyone suggest why listener is not working?

i expected to navigate to the screen when listener is called.

```
BlocConsumer<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
      bloc: homebloc,
      listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is HomeActionState,
      buildWhen: (previous, current) => current is! HomeActionState,
      // listenWhen: (previous, current) => true,
      // buildWhen: (previous, current) => true,
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is HomeNavigateToCartPageActionState) {
          print('object');
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const Cart(),
            ),
          );
        } else if (state is HomeNavigateToWhislistPageActionState) {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const Wishlist(),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Shoaib Grocery App'),
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    homebloc.add(HomeWhislistButtonNavigateEvent());
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_border)),
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    homebloc.add(HomeCartButtonNavigateEvent());
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.shopping_bag_outlined,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Initial-state does not get call on listener afaik.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable answer is that you have put a parameter that says to listen only when this state appears.

Try to remove the below code from yours and Test it again.

```
listenWhen: (previous, current) => current is HomeActionState,
```